# Como fazer aparecer e esconder um menu?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, javascript-eventos

Como fazer o menu aparecer e esconder? Não estou conseguindo.

Código:

```js
let close = document.querySelector('.btn-menu')

close.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var menu = document.querySelector('.menu')
  if (menu.style.display == 'none') {
    menu.style.display = 'show'
  }
})
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="cabecalho">
    <a href="index.html">
      <h1 class="logo">NodeProp - Especializado em Soluções Digitais</h1>
      <button class="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i></button>
    </a>
    <nav class="menu">
      <a  class="btn-close">x</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Home</a></li>
        <li><a>Cursos</a></li>
        <li><a>Sites</a></li>
        <li><a>Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a>Blog</a></li>
        <li><a>Publi</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: `if (menu.style.display !== 'block') { menu.style.display = 'block'; }`

Comment: O problema também é que o botão de _toggle_ está **dentro** do link. Quando você clica nele, você é redirecionado para a próxima página — no caso, `index.html`.

Comment: Entendi Luiz Felipe, muito obrigado, Fico grato pela resposta. Valeu!!!

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, não existe `display: show` no CSS. Conforme apontado nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/479023/como-fazer-aparecer-e-esconder-um-menu#comment897696_479023), o ideal neste caso é utilizar `display: block` como *oposto* ao `display: none`, de modo a mostrar o menu.

O `block` é ideal neste caso já que é o padrão para a propriedade `display` para elementos `<nav>`.

Um outro problema é que o botão de fechar está **dentro** da âncora (`<a>`). Desse modo, embora o *handler* de evento do JavaScript seja propriamente executado ao clicar no botão, o usuário será redirecionado ao `href` do link, o que evidentemente não é a ação desejada.

Corrigindo esses problemas (e com algumas outras mudanças), ficamos com:

```js
let open = document.querySelector('.btn-menu');
let close = document.querySelector('.btn-close');
let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

open.addEventListener('click', function() {
  menu.style.display = 'block';
});

close.addEventListener('click', function() {
  menu.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header class="cabecalho">
  <h1 class="logo">
    <a href="index.html">NodeProp - Especializado em Soluções Digitais</a>
  </h1>
  
  <!-- Note que agora o botão de fechar está fora do link. -->
  <button class="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i></button>
  
  <nav class="menu">
    <a  class="btn-close">x</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Cursos</a></li>
      <li><a>Sites</a></li>
      <li><a>Jobs</a></li>
      <li><a>Blog</a></li>
      <li><a>Publi</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Mas eu fiz algumas mudanças:

1. Como existem dois botões separados (um para abrir e outro para fechar), não há, evidentemente, a necessidade de se utilizar um `if`, já que o botão para abrir *sempre* fará o menu ser mostrado e o para fechar, *sempre* fará o menu ser escondido.
2. Removi o `<h1>` de dentro do `<a>` e coloquei o `<a>` dentro do `<h1>` (inverti o aninhamento). Fiz isso porque o elemento `<a>` foi feito para aceitar dentro de si somente elementos inline (e o `<h1>` não é *inline*). [Saiba mais nesta pergunta do SOen.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3379392/7445826)
3. Adicionei ponto e vírgula no final de cada *statement*. Pode parecer "frescura" e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não os usar, como [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [esta](/q/432960) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341)).

Mas se você quiser, pode adicionar um único *handler* aos dois botões e fazer a verificação com o `if`. Assim:

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-menu, .btn-close');
let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

// Como agora temos uma lista de elementos, precisamos de usar o `forEach`
// para adicionar o listener de evento a cada um deles.
btns.forEach((btn) => btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (menu.style.display !== 'block') {
    menu.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    menu.style.display = 'none';
  }
}));
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header class="cabecalho">
  <h1 class="logo">
    <a href="index.html">NodeProp - Especializado em Soluções Digitais</a>
  </h1>
  
  <!-- Note que agora o botão de fechar está fora do link. -->
  <button class="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i></button>
  
  <nav class="menu">
    <a  class="btn-close">x</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Cursos</a></li>
      <li><a>Sites</a></li>
      <li><a>Jobs</a></li>
      <li><a>Blog</a></li>
      <li><a>Publi</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```